# Leaflet / Mapbox.js: incorrect Popup offset using divIcon with CSS class

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, popup, markers

I'm having an error which I can't seem to find elsewhere online with Leaflet / mapbox.js regarding the offset of a popup from a marker's custom icon which has been set with `L.divIcon` and using a CSS class to style:

[image: Incorrect Popup positioning, set to marker icon's anchor point]

Here's the invocation of the `L.divIcon`:

```
var icon = L.divIcon({
  'iconSize': [30, 40],
  'iconAnchor': [15, 40],
  'className': 'mapview-marker-icon'
})
```

The CSS class also has the width and height set:

```
.mapview-marker-icon {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -40px 0 0 -15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
}
```

One thing I've found is that if I don't set the `iconSize` and the `iconAnchor` in the JS, then the marker's icon is overridden by mapbox.js / Leaflets's CSS styles applied directly to the element ([mapbox.js documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-divicon/) suggests that `iconSize` and `iconAnchor` can be set via CSS classes and don't need to be set in JS):

[image: I was also playing with <code>display</code> props to <code>block</code> and <code>inline-block</code> to see if that changed anything. It didn't.]

(note: I was also playing with `display` props to `block` and `inline-block` to see if that changed anything. It didn't.)

When I use `L.mapbox.marker.icon` the popup offset is correct:

```
var icon = L.mapbox.marker.icon({
    'marker-size': 'large',
    'marker-color': '#000'
})
```

[image: Ideal Popup position, except want to use with custom <code>L.divIcon</code>]

Is there something I'm missing on the CSS or JS side of things? The popup is applied using [`L.Marker.bindPopup()`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-marker/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just forgetting about the [`popupAnchor`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#icon-popupanchor) option of `L.Icon`/`L.DivIcon`.

Comment: Ah ha, there you go. I thought perhaps it wasn't an option since the documentation on mapbox.js didn't mention that property explicitly (they specify that `icon` takes `icon options` and `divIcon` takes `divIcon options`). Should have checked Leaflet documentation...

Comment: Yeah, but the `L.DivIcon` options inherit from the `L.Icon` options. This is reflected in the Leaflet 1.0.0 docs, but might not be reflected in other docs.